# full screen responsive background image with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to twitters bootstrap. What want to know is the HTML mockup that i have to use for a full screen responsive background image with bootstrap?

certainly I'm suing the mockup

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="wrapper">

</div>


</div>
```

Before the wrapper i do have a navigation menu. I want to add a full screen image to div class wrapper. and i want wrapper div to scale 100%. any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should consider looking at some examples

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Two options

1. use `img-responsive` class if you are using  tag.

   ```
   <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="pic_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
   </div>
   ```
2. if you are using css use this.

   ```
   .wrapper{background: url('/assets/64531/green_suburb.jpg') no-repeat   center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;}
   ```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work on Chrome for Android for me. Is there a workaround for that?