# How to make a fullscreen image on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is an example: https://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio/

In the example there is the background landing page that fills the width of the viewport, doesn't take up the width of the whole page, and is responsive. How do you use bootstrap to hand code an image like this?

Comment: There are a LOT of articles about this. Try searching a bit. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721935/full-screen-responsive-background-image-with-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [article](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), you just have to define a div with an id and put the image inside like this:

```
 <div id="bg">
    <img src="yourimg.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
```

and then give this styles:

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}


.back {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

}
```

This should do the trick.
  You can see this in action and play  [here](http://jsbin.com/codumo/edit?html,css,output) *( for viewing in fullscreen just hit the arrow in the right corner next to "Auto-run js")*.

Answer (score 0):

You use this to fill the tag:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```